# Massive ORM and inheritance

Tags: c#, orm, massive

Does the micro ORM "massive" have a way of handling inheritance?

[robconery / massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive)

Is it hard to write a provider for Massive?

I've got a need for something very close to SQL Server.  As a first step, it'd be good to just intercept the SQL generated by Massive, and then push that into my database of choice.

Possibly doing something like this would have the desired inherited effect:

```
    class Products:DynamicModel{...}

    class BabyProducts : Products {...}
```

---

Is it possible to link "Products" to a dynamic model via an attribute instead of through inheritance?

N.B. this project (inspired by Massive) might be a closer fit: http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/

still not sure about inheritance.

---

On providers... MicroORMs that *only* extend IDbConnection such as http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ might the best place to start.  Not sure what this means in terms of Massive yet.

Comment: Voting to close because this question seems rhetorical.  Experiment first, and when you get stuck, ask a question.  Then you'll have some code to post, which will both show people you've given an honest try at solving your own problem, and will give them a diving board to jump from when answering.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: 1. I try to write questions like this so that they'll be useful to newbies and experienced alike, so maybe you've misread the "tone" of the post.  2. I have the source code from git and am working my way through it.  3. can't actually use the ORM right now because my DB isn't currently supported... so can't write those specific examples you asked for. 4. two aspects (providers & inheritance) are things I could really use the voice of experience on with regards to this ORM. Are either of these a weakness?

Comment: Since I haven't used massive, I will admit that I may have misread your post.  The first question `Does the micro ORM "massive" have a way of handling inheritance?` is perfectly legit.  The second `Is it hard to write a provider for Massive?` is subjective, and might make more sense as "What would it take to write a provider for Massive?".  The third `is there a way to shoehorn a POCO based model into a Massive DynamicModel? Probably not` is rhetorical.  I guess if the main thrust of the question is inheritance, then it's a fine question.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: thanks for feedback.  I reworded the rhetorical question.  Not sure how to reword the subjective one... possibly someone will have a blog post on how they approached this for their favourite DB.  Maybe I'll find that myself through more googling and put the link in there myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'm going to go with Dapper for now:

http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Tests/Tests.cs

Dapper is definitely database independent *and* it handles inheritance

Search for TestInheritance() in the Tests.cs above for an example.